# Uncaught Error: Route parameter missing: id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I'm building a social network site and I'm using AJAX to refresh when people post on the website. I get this error when I use this code. I'm also using handlebars. Looks like the AJAX request communicates to my server just fine, it's just not appearing within the browser appropriately. Here's what My code looks like:

```
window.loadedActivities = [];

var addActivity = function(item) {
  var found = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < window.loadedActivities.length; i++) {
    if (window.loadedActivities[i].id == item.id) {
      var found = true;
    }
  }

  if (!found) {
    window.loadedActivities.push(item);
    window.loadedActivities.sort(function(a, b) {
      var returnValue;
      if (a.created_at > b.created_at)
        returnValue = -1;
      if (b.created_at > a.created_at)
        returnValue = 1;
      if (a.created_at == b.created_at)
        returnValue = 0;
      return returnValue;
    });
  }

  return item;
}

var renderActivities = function() {
  var source = $('#activities-template').html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template({
    activities: window.loadedActivities, 
    count: window.loadedActivities.length
  });
  var $activityFeedLink = $('li#activity-feed');

  $activityFeedLink.addClass('dropdown');
  $activityFeedLink.html(html);
  $activityFeedLink.find('a.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
}

var pollActivity = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: Routes.activities_path({format: 'json', since: window.lastFetch}),
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      window.lastFetch = Math.floor((new Date).getTime() / 1000);
      if (data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          addActivity(data[i]);
        }
         //Crashes here
        renderActivities();
      }
    }
  });
}

Handlebars.registerHelper('activityFeedLink', function() {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(Routes.activities_path());
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('activityLink', function() {
  var link, path, html;
  var activity = this;
  var linkText = activity.targetable_type.toLowerCase();

  switch (linkText) {
    case "status":
      path = Routes.status_path(activity.targetable_id);
      break;

    case "userfriendship":
      path = Routes.profile_path(activity.profile_name);
      linkText = "friend";
      break;
  }

  if (activity.action === 'deleted') {
    path = '#';
  }

  html = "<li><a href='" + path + "'>" + this.user_name + " " + this.action + " a " + linkText + ".</a></li>";
  return new Handlebars.SafeString( html );
});

window.pollInterval = window.setInterval( pollActivity, 5000 );
pollActivity();
```

Looks like the code crashes when calling the rendered activities method within the pollActivity function. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!